# Corda: Newly added Corda node on a local machine can't be reached by other nodes

Tags: corda

I have created a 3 node Corda network on a Linux instance and can initiate and complete flows between the 3 nodes of the network. However when I added a 4th node to the network on the same Linux Instance, any of the nodes in the existing network are unable to complete flows with the 4th node.

Here is the configuration of an existing node:

```
myLegalName="O=PartyA,L=Mumbai,C=IN"
p2pAddress="198.136.234.245:10005"
rpcSettings {
    address="localhost:10006"
    adminAddress="localhost:10046"
}
rpcUsers=[
    {
        password=test
        permissions=[
            ALL
        ]
        user=user1
    }
]
dataSourceProperties = {
    dataSourceClassName = "org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource"
    "dataSource.url" = "jdbc:postgresql://10.0.0.4:5432/postgres"
    "dataSource.user" = test2
    "dataSource.password" = test2p
}

database = {
    transactionIsolationLevel = READ_COMMITTED
    schema = test2
}

jarDirs = ['/home/ubuntu/java/postgres']
webAddress="198.136.234.245:10007"

Here is the configuration of a newly added node:

myLegalName="O=PartyB,L=Delhi,C=IN"
p2pAddress="198.136.234.245:10014"
rpcSettings {
    address="localhost:10015"
    adminAddress="localhost:10055"
}
rpcUsers=[
    {
        password=test
        permissions=[
            ALL
        ]
        user=user1
    }
]
dataSourceProperties = {
    dataSourceClassName = "org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource"
    "dataSource.url" = "jdbc:postgresql://10.0.0.4:5432/postgres"
    "dataSource.user" = test5
    "dataSource.password" = test5p
}

database = {
    transactionIsolationLevel = READ_COMMITTED
    schema = test5
}

jarDirs = ['/home/ubuntu/java/postgres']
webAddress="198.136.234.245:10016"

Here's the message in PartyA's log file:
[INFO ] 2019-07-05T13:27:02,457Z [Node thread-1] flow.[ae2549c0-9bfd-4226-9625-653bc79322b0].initiateSession - Initiating flow session with party O=PartyB, L=Delhi, C=IN. Session id for tracing purposes is SessionId(toLong=5939067804807479907). {}



[INFO ] 2019-07-05T13:27:14,277Z [nioEventLoopGroup-2-4] netty.AMQPClient.operationComplete - Failed to connect to 198.136.234.245:10014 {}

...

[INFO ] 2019-07-05T13:27:15,278Z [nioEventLoopGroup-2-5] netty.AMQPClient.run - Retry connect to 198.136.234.245:10014 {}
```

Answer (score 0):

`deployNodes` bootstraps the network. In short, the generated nodes know about each other and nothing else. Adding a new node to the network without running `deployNodes` will leave the original nodes communicating with each other but they will not see the new node. The new node will also not see the original nodes.

To resolve this, you can rebuild your network using `deployNodes`.

Or, you will need a network map which will handle the distribution of identities as nodes join the network. An implementation can be found [here](https://gitlab.com/cordite/network-map-service).

Comment: Thank you, Dan! I will try network map, I don't want to constantly run deployNodes when we go in a production environment and add nodes.